# Usage of “ of” in sentences below

Tags: prepositions

I do not know how to use 'of' when describing an amount, measurement or belonging. Here are some examples to explain what I have tried and what I want to achieve. Could you please explain the mistakes I have made?

> 1)I need transparent one of this a square meter sheet .
>
> 2)I need screwable one of this type of table leg.
>
> 3)I need cheaper one of this model of t-shirt.

1)The Seller showed me colorfull plastic sheets of one square meter but I told him that I need transparent a sheet. And I said this sentence.

2)I need a toilet paper holder which I can screw on the wall, but the holder they have just can be sticked on the wall. Is sentence 3 be correct?

3) I saw my friends t-shirt. When I learned its price I thought it is too expensive and I said: 'Cheaper one of this t-shirt'.

Are all uses of 'of' correct to describe what I try to say?If any of my suggestions are wrong correct them?

Answer (score 1):

(1) "I need one the same size as these, only transparent."

"I need a square meter of transparent plastic."

(2) (What does a table leg have to do with it?) "I need one of those that can be screwed to the wall."

(3) "I need a cheaper style of T-shirt."

"I need a T-shirt like this one, only cheaper."

Answer (score 1):

[quantity] **of** [noun phrase *in the plural*]

For example:

> two of these sheet**s**
>
> one of the toilet-paper holder**s** that can be fastened to the wall with screws
>
> three of the yellow apple**s**

Answer (score -1):

Sentences 2 and 3 I believe would be grammatically correct if you added an article "a" after "need". e.g.  "I need a screwable one of this type of table leg."

As far as I can think that sentence is 'correct', but sounds a little ponderous and unidiomatic.  A general format for "one of" sentences which sounds more idiomatic (British English) would be: "I need a(n) [[adjective]] one of [[this/these/those]]".  Where this/these/those (table leg, t-shirt) is often left unsaid, since it is clearly established by prior conversational context, gesture, etc: "I need a screwable one of these" (**holding up table leg**).

In the event that you need to add the extra qualification, I think it would perhaps sound more natural to replace "one" in your sentences with "version" - e.g. "I need a screwable **version** of this type of table leg",  but that's subjective.  "One" is perfectly understandable.

Sentence 1, the above observations also generally apply.  A natural (Br.Eng) phrasing would be "I need a transparent one of these/those square meter sheets."

Answer (score -1):

I need **1 screw-on  table leg this like this one**.
OR
I need **one of these screw-on table legs**.

I need a cheaper model of this T-shirt.

I need 1 of these transparent, one-square meter sheets.

You need to work **on adjective placement.**

If you use one of, what comes afterwards has to be plural.

I need one of these fine, cotton towels.